# How to filter source file using gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

Is there any plugin or solution to filter source file. When i am using maven there is plugin https://github.com/wavesoftware/templating-maven-plugin

That plugin work like a charm is there any solution for gradle, to achieve the same result.

For example i am crate interface that holds all information about build:

```
public interface BuildConfig {

public static final String PROFILE_FAST = "fast";
public static final String PROFILE_DEV = "dev";
public static final String PROFILE_TEST = "test";
public static final String PROFILE_UAT = "uat";
public static final String PROFILE_PROD = "prod";

public static final String APP_CODE = "${app-code}";
public static final String PROFILE_ID = "${profile-id}";
public static final String APP_VERSION = "${project.version}";
public static final boolean DEBUG = !("${profile-id}").equals(PROFILE_PROD);
}
```

thanks

Comment: can you elaborate your usecase? you can use 'exclude' definitions in processResources task, compile or directly in your sourceSet setup

Comment: Now i am edit my question, i am using templating-maven-plugin that very easy provide information about build process and maven properties.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Yes, there are valid situations that you need to filter source files, e.g. everything contained in webapp folder as part of a WAR.